# TCP client in Boost asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, tcpclient

Im building a TCP client using Boost::asio Libs. My program has a write() thread that sends a command to the server

```
write(*_socket,boost::asio::buffer("sspi l1\n\n",sizeof("sspi l1\n\n")));
```

Then a read thread is started that reads from the buffer all the time, as there can be messages broadcasted from the server due to any other client

```
void TCP_IP_Connection::readTCP()
{

size_t l=0;

 this->len=0;
boost::system::error_code error;


try
  {//loop reading all values from router
   while(1)
     {

      //wait for reply??


    l=_socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(this->reply,sizeof(this->reply)),error);
    if(error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);

    if(l>0)
    {

        this->dataProcess(l);

    }
    else
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));


      _io.run();

       if(error==boost::asio::error::eof) //connection closed by router
         std::cout<<"connection closed by router";

       _io.reset();

     }

   }

catch (std::exception& e)
 {
   std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
 }

}
```

This thread runs al time in a while(1) loop and is supposed to sleep when the received data length is less than zero. It reads all the data and calls the data parser function. After that the write thread is used to send another command, with read thread running. But instead of the required response the server sends back

```
  ? ""
ERROR: Unknown command
```

I tried using the wireshark. I can see the command being send properly. What can be mistake I'm doing here?

Comment: If you see the right command being sent then why do you assume the problem is in the code that sends the command? If the server won't accept the command, it's pretty sure that the command is wrong or you need some authentication. But that has nothing to do with C++, Boost or anything related.

Comment: Actually I thought so, but the command is correct and there is no authentication problem. Only tip i got was there is something wrong with the write buffer. But being a beginner I really can't find out what I can do there.

Comment: You say you have a reader and writer thread, but I see no mutex protecting your _socket. Perhaps you have threading problems? What happens if you send the same commands by hand in a terminal program?

Comment: if I send using netcat, the server responds correctly. About mutex, is it about locking the socket for reading and writing?

Comment: from the accepted answer I suppose you did not send the right command - you sent the command and an additional trailing `\0` which the server was not very happy about.

Comment: Yup.. din't think about the null character at end of string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizeof("sspi l1\n\n") returns 10, but I can only count 9 characters in that string.

Try this instead:

```
const std::string cmd("sspi l1\n\n");
write(*_socket,boost::asio::buffer(cmd, cmd.length()));
```

Or when you have it as a string it is enough to do

```
const std::string cmd("sspi l1\n\n");
write(*_socket,boost::asio::buffer(cmd));
```

The second argument specifies a maximum length of the string to use. But since it is a constant string, the second argument is not strictly necessary.